# POSTGRES pgplsql psql command line argument

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a sql block(file.sql) as :

```
DO $$
DECLARE 

 var1 varchar;
BEGIN

    var1 := :key;

END $$;
```

When I invoke this .sql with psql,

```
psql -h localhost -v key="value" -U user -f file.sql  postgredb
```

I get an error :

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"

Would like to know why the command line arg is not getting resolved

Comment: I don't think you can use `psql` variables inside a PL/pgSQL block

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it like that.
I'd create a psql function that takes one argument of varchar (e.g. key in your example) and then I'd invoke it from the terminal with:

`psql -h localhost -U user postgredb -c "select updateValue('someValue');"`

You can then wrap all that in some bash script of function so that you can invoke it faster?.

Hope that helps, cheers.